# Connecting different voltage pins - 3.3 V logic to 1.8 V

Tags: microcontroller

I have 2 MCUs working from different voltage supply levels, and their ground pins are connected. MCU1 is running on 1.8V and all of its GPIO pins are pulled to VCC 1.8V. These are active low pins, so I want to connect them to another MCU (an ESP32) which runs on VCC 3.3V. Eventually the pins pulled low using MCU2. The question is, what is the best way to avoid damaging MCU1, if MCU2 IO pin voltage accidentally goes high to 3.3V? Should I use voltage divider on this pin, optocoupler or what?

[image]

Comment: Use an [I2C Level Translator](https://www.google.com/search?q=i2c+level+translator).

Comment: I have 22 GPIO pins to drive like that, so I want to minimize the component count. But thanks for the suggestion, I will take a look to this.

Comment: You only need a single N-Channel MOSFET (in addition to a pull-up resistor on each side). You can get these in packages with multiple parts in each to reduce overall package count.

Comment: What speed do you need?

Comment: brhans, thank you, I will go with this probably!

winny, Very low speed, what I want is to programmatically emulate button presses on a gaming controller. Like the way a person presses buttons in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Can MCU2's IO be configured as "open-collector" style output so that it can only pull low? Or toggle it between low and tri-state (so the output is floating and let R1 pull to 1.8 V)?

You'd need to guarantee that it can't pull high during power-up.

---

From the comments:

> Lets say MCU1 is powered, and there is 1.8V on that pin, while MCU2 is not powered, so I can't configure the GPIO pin just yet to be open drain, because no supply present. In this case, can I damage MCU2?

MCU1 will always be configured as an input so the only voltage/current source is R1. MCU2 will have some sort of diode protection on the IO which will shunt the current to its Vcc so it *should* protect it. I don't know for sure.

The easy way to protect against that sort of fault is to power the 1.8 V regulator from the 3.3 V regulator. That way MCU2 will always be powered by a higher voltage than MCU1 and the situation you've described can't occur.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! MCU2 is an ESP32, its GPIO pins can be configured as open drain (GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_OD). I also worry about the independent power supplies, it can be that one of them is not powered and I don't know what may happen in that case.

Comment: With open-drain connection you wouldn't have to worry provided that R1 can't pull up. This is solved by making sure that R1 is connected to MCU1's Vcc (rather than to some other Vcc).

Comment: Lets say MCU1 is powered, and there is 1.8V on that pin, while MCU2 is not powered, so I can't configure the GPIO pin just yet to be open drain, because no supply present. In this case, can I damage MCU2?

Answer (score 1):

Below, Q1 completely isolates the the two IO pins. When MCU2 is off, its protection diodes cannot sink current via R1, and the low output potential will not switch on Q1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk1AFT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The only way MCU1 input IN can be low, is if Q1 is switched on, and the only way that can happen is if MCU2 is both powered and has its output OUT set high.

OUT can have any potential, and either MCU can be powered or unpowered in any combination, without damaging either MCU.

It inverts though.

Comment: No problem with inverting. Thanks a lot!